# How do I optimize a spatial query in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, spatial-query, st-union

I'm trying to speed up my query which should return only these polygons that are not completly overlapped by polygons above them.

My tables looks like this:

> Map -> Layer -> Object

The object table has a generated geometry field and an spatial index on that:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_object_polygon ON object USING gist(postgis_area_geometry);
```

My layer-table has an order field, so a layer with sort_order value of 10 is above a layer with a sort_order value of 5. some layer are always on top, so the field is just null.

There are a total of 33556 Objects split in 22 layers.
For this specific layer, my query takes 12 sec. There are 12 layer above this specific layer, the highest layer (sort_value = null) usually contains the most polygons, in this case about 28.000.

This calculation takes almost 2 minutes for all of my layers.

My first idea was to cache the union result, so PostGIS don't have to recalculate it every time, the user have to recalculate this union result once in a while to keep it up to date though.
But ST_Union is not the bottleneck here, I probably would safe a minute in total if I'm lucky. Maybe the union is not covered by the spatial index but I'm not sure.

Any ideas how to improve this query?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    object
WHERE
    object.layer_id = 267 AND
    NOT ST_CONTAINS
    (
        (
            SELECT
                st_union(object.postgis_area_geometry)
            FROM
                object
                LEFT JOIN layer ON layer.id = object.layer_id
            WHERE
                layer.map_id = 22 AND
                (layer.sort_order > 10 OR layer.sort_order IS NULL)
        ),
        object.postgis_area_geometry
    );
```

Explain:

```
Index Scan using ix_object_layer on object object  (cost=13022.91..31276.17 rows=648 width=855)
  Index Cond: (layer_id = 267)
"  Filter: (NOT st_contains($0, postgis_area_geometry))"
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=13022.61..13022.62 rows=1 width=32)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=6.08..11918.61 rows=8632 width=202)
                Hash Cond: (object_1.layer_id = layer.id)
                ->  Seq Scan on object object_1  (cost=0.00..11760.79 rows=55879 width=210)
                ->  Hash  (cost=5.84..5.84 rows=19 width=8)
                      ->  Seq Scan on layer layer  (cost=0.00..5.84 rows=19 width=8)
                            Filter: (((sort_order > 10) OR (sort_order IS NULL)) AND (map_id = 22))
```

Comment: please add the output of `explain` on your queries

Comment: sry, just added

Comment: for one, use `st_collect` instead of `st_union`

Comment: add geometry index on layer; add indexes on layer for id, map_id, sort_order;  add index on object for layer_id;  add foreign key between object and layer for id and layer_id.

Comment: @jbalk If I replace st_union to st_collect I get an error
ERROR: GEOSContains: TopologyException: side location conflict at xxxx.
All Geometries are valid by checking with st_isValid and not a single polygon has holes, so I assume Postgis create his own invalid polygons somehow.

Not sure how to add a geometry index on the layer, because the layer-table has no geometry type column...
index on object for layer_id, fk between object and layer, index on layer for id, map_id already exists but sort_order, here I'm not sure what benefits I would get.

Comment: Collect does not alter your geometries.  Union does.  That tells me that something is wrong with your geometries.  You can try normalizing your geometry before collecting - `st_collect(st_normalize(geom))`.  Just a guess, but using `st_coveredby` or `st_covers` instead of `st_contains` might work, since points on the boundaries are included in covers and not included in contains.

Comment: still getting the same error message using st_normalize. st_coveredby is fast but returns all geometries and st_coverts is still too slow but thx anyway, the accepted answer is doing great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should filter your data with your object geom before you union them. By focussing on only the geom that can intersect your geom, you can make use of the index filter, and depending on the situation you can possibly gain a lot of compute time.

Here is an idea on what it can look like:

```
WITH new_object AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        postgis_area_geometry
    FROM
        object
    WHERE
        object.layer_id = 267
), above_objects AS (
    SELECT
        object.postgis_area_geometry as above_geom
    FROM
        object
        LEFT JOIN layer ON layer.id = object.layer_id
    WHERE
        layer.map_id = 22 AND
        (layer.sort_order > 10 OR layer.sort_order IS NULL)
), new_object_with_above AS (
    SELECT
        new_object.id,
        new_object.postgis_area_geometry,
        ST_Union(above_geom) as above_geoms
    FROM
        new_object
    LEFT JOIN
        above_objects
    ON ST_Intersects(new_object.postgis_area_geometry, above_objects.above_geom)
    GROUP BY new_object.id, new_object.postgis_area_geometry
)
SELECT
    id,
    postgis_area_geometry
FROM
    new_object_with_above
WHERE
    above_geoms IS NULL 
    OR NOT ST_CONTAINS
    (
        above_geoms,
        postgis_area_geometry
    );
```

Note: I decomposed it with CTE to try to be more clear, but there is probably more efficient ways of doing this. Be sure to try this on postgres 12 or above, otherwise you probably need to rewrite this query without CTE or you will probably not use geom index, as it will materialized each step instead of being more clever. Also, I didn't test it, maybe it's not doing much and you can try to rewrite it for example looking into `LATERAL` type of join to do the same idea ?

Comment: Did you mean to pass above_objects.above_geom as second parameter for st_intersects? "...ST_Intersects(new_object.postgis_area_geometry, above_objects.above_geom)". I actually had the same idea to filter first the intersecting geometries but the problem is, that these polygons now HAVE TO intersect with objects above them, so I lose all objects that have no intersecting objects, which I dont like :/ But other then that I get huge performance boost. from 12 sec to 1 sec execution time

Comment: Yes sorry you're right, I edited the ST_Intersects. And no, it's a left join so you keep the objects even when nothing intersects, but it was filtered in the last request (I added `above_geoms IS NULL` to keep them)

Comment: thank you very much, works perfectly :) btw. the second parameter for intersection is called above_geoms because of the alias :)

Comment: You're right again, I edited too fast, I fixed it :)